# Ubuntu 22.04 Wifi Stops and then system hangs if I restart networking

Tags: networking, network-manager

Having this weird problem for some time. Wifi (5GHz) disconnects after some time; Restarting networking basically hangs the system. On the latest kernel as of now

```
sudo service networking restart
```

System

```
alex@pop-os:~$ uname -r
5.18.10-76051810-generic
alex@pop-os:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Pop!_OS"
VERSION="22.04 LTS"
ID=pop
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
PRETTY_NAME="Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
HOME_URL="https://pop.system76.com"
SUPPORT_URL="https://support.system76.com"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://system76.com/privacy"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
LOGO=distributor-logo-pop-os
alex@pop-os:~$
```

Solution tried but not working

Solution tried- Set power saving to off; Default was 3; Set it to 2

```
$ sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
wifi.powersave = 2
```

Reboot is needed after this

Comment: Pop OS is not an official Ubuntu flavor and thus off-topic here.

Comment: This should affect the Ubuntu users as well; as it is mostly Ubuntu based in networking ; except in GUI and GPU parts